# Sapling tree add on: leaves over multiple branch levels

Tags: sapling-addon

I want to make a fir or spruce tree, but am actually stuck with generating the leaves/needles. They appear only on the last level of the branches, but on a real spruce there would be needles on the lower branches as well. 
Am I able to do this with the sapling add on?

Comment: I basically took the douglas fir preset, added 2 more levels of branches (4 totel) and activated leaves. The leaves appeared only on the 4th level in this case.

Comment: Leaves apparently only show up on the highest branch level alone. Maybe create two separate trees with the exact same settings but different branch levels, then erase the trunk and keep only the leaves.

Comment: I see. You can still go with Sapling for the leaves as in the end it won't be quite visible how many are there on the branch. Take a look at [Blender HD tutorial](https://youtu.be/mGFGuL8bfdI?list=PLAOTJUe747COZN7FoLEVD5en_AIK7sbgw) about creating pine trees for some ideas how to accomplish that